# Fitnesse extending TestResponder and overriding classpath location

Tags: java, testing, fitnesse

I'm started using fitnesse recently and came across the issue of having to hard code my jar paths in the tests.

I came across a few old tutorials which explaing that extending test responder you can set the classpath for example for this version:

```
/** For FitNesse 20081115
protected String buildClassPath() throws Exception {
    return super.buildClassPath() + PATH_SEPARATOR + getInheritedClassPath();
}

protected String getInheritedClassPath() {
    String inheritedClasspath = "";
    String parentClassPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String[] classPathElements = parentClassPath.split(PATH_SEPARATOR);
    for (String element : classPathElements) {
        inheritedClasspath += PATH_SEPARATOR + "\"" + element + "\"";
    }
    return inheritedClasspath;
}
```

I am however using the latest version and the buildClassPath() method is not available, any ideas anyone how to go about this?